# Get static property by string

Tags: c#

I have `public static class MyClass` which contains many `public static string` parameters.

Following I have some value

```
string val = "something";
```

Using that `val` I want to be able to get specified property - like `MyClass.something`.
How can I do that ?

Comment: You want MyClass.something to return the string "val" or are you trying to get a property value by it's name?  The question is a bit unclear, could you give a usage sample of the code?

Comment: Sorry. I have no code right now, but answering for your question, I want to get a property value by it's name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("something");
string something = (string) propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to review your code. IMHO, Getting properties through Reflection is not the best idea. So if you rewrite your code, that properties would be stored not in static fields, but in `Dictionary<string, string>`. Here is example:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> Properites = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string Property1 { get {return Properties["Property1"];} }
    public string Property2 { get {return Properties["Property2"];} }
}
```

After that you can call it using `MyClass.Property1` or `MyClass.Properties["Property1"]`.