# How can i use variables in (.) statements in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so i am trying to make a code that changes the color of my character/gameobject (a simple cube)

i am doing this by having a button and clicking on it will set a variable called PlayerColor
to White,Red,Bue basically whatever i write in the inspector.
[I write whatever i want there and it puts it into the variable PlayerColor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grj6Y.png)

and here in code i try to change the color of my gameobject according to what the variable has but obviously it doesnt let me so thats why i'm here :D.
[Here is my try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYEeX.png)

searching in google didnt really help as i couldnt really find any answers because desribing this sitation in a google search is very hard and it shows unrelated things as a result (as in when i searched "How to use variables in (.) statements in c#")

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please don't post images of code or text. You need to create a [MCVE] to receive a proper answer. Otherwise your question will be closed.

Comment: You may just missing a semicolon `;` on at the end of the line of code with the red squiggle. Can you please also tell us what errors you are getting when you attempt to compile or run the code?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924480/unity-get-random-color-at-spawning/54924677#54924677)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get static property by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422250/get-static-property-by-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **Reflection**. Put `using System.Reflection;` at the top of your script and then:

```
public void ChangePlayerMaterial( string playerColor )
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Color).GetProperty( playerColor.ToLower() );
    if( propertyInfo != null )
    {
        Color color = (Color) propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);
        PlayerMat.color = color ;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("The color " + playerColor + " does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though i dont understand the code, it really works. Thanks Hellium !

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) will help you understand what is reflection.